Reducing OR not working as expected when bit slicing in a loop
As for the title reducing OR not working as expected when bit slicing in a loop.
This is an extract of what I have:
logic [3:0][1:0]  quad_mask_dq_qq; 
logic [1:0]       dfifo_rrdy_qq;


always_comb begin
         for (int qq = 0; qq < 2; qq++) begin
            dfifo_rrdy_qq[qq] =  (|quad_mask_dq_qq[2*qq +: 1]);
         end
end

Example of quad_mask_dq_qq = {2,0,0,1}
Expectation of dfifo_rrdy_qq = {1,1} what I actually got = {0,1}
My expectation are, writing it more explicitly, that the slicing would be the same as doing:
dfifo_rrdy_qq[0] =  (|quad_mask_dq_qq[1:0]);
dfifo_rrdy_qq[1] =  (|quad_mask_dq_qq[3:2]);
Is something with the looping I am not considering here?

In order to make this work you need to reduce two array elements at a time.
The current design is reducing a single element.
module tb ();

  logic [3:0][1:0] quad_mask_dq_qq = '{2'b10, 2'b00, 2'b00, 2'b01}; 
  logic [1:0]      dfifo_rrdy_qq;
  
  localparam NUM_ELEM_TO_REDUCE = 2;

  always_comb begin

    for (int qq = 0; qq < 2; qq++) begin
      //  dfifo_rrdy_qq[qq] =  ( | (quad_mask_dq_qq[2 * qq +: 1]));

      // ----------------------------------------------------------------
      // Reduce two elements at a time, not one
      // ----------------------------------------------------------------
      dfifo_rrdy_qq[qq] =  ( | quad_mask_dq_qq[2 * qq +: NUM_ELEM_TO_REDUCE] );

      $display("reduction = %0b", dfifo_rrdy_qq[qq]);

    end
  end

endmodule

Prints
reduction = 1    
reduction = 1

In the  part select operation a +: b
the b term is the size ('take b elements starting at a')
The code in the post reduces over one element.
See IEEE 1800-2017 Standard for SystemVerilog Section 7.4.6 Indexing and slicing of arrays

Yeah, this is the issue. So simple and yet I couldn't see it.
Thanks @Mikef :)

I always have to slow down and think about how the slicing with that operator works.
